# Need to push the .yml file into multiple repositories with custom modifications

Tags: linux, bash, git, shell, yaml

I have developed a shell script that help me to add source.yml file to all repos but i got struck with few blocks

> need to push to all git repos (100) ie. how to add that source.yml file to all repos
> How to update the given below variable 1,2 from metadata according to the repo name for suppose repo name is developer then the metadata inside source.yaml file, the variable-1,2 should be replace with developer.

Here the scenario

I need to add a source.yml file into multiple repositories(100) with variable configuration

> In .yml file, metadata consists of projectKey(variable-1(Current-reponame)) & FriendlyName(variable-2(current-reponame))where these variable values should change according to repo name

```
apiVersion: v9
metadata:
askId: ABCDE123-45678
caAgileId: ABC
//com.ABC is common for all repos (yourproduct.yourApp.yourComponent) 
variable-1(current repo name)
// (YourApp-SomeComponent) - variable-2(current repo name)
projectKey: com.ABC.yourproduct.yourApp.yourComponent
FriendlyName: YourApp-SomeComponent
componentType: code
targetQG: GATE_77
```

Please help me with how to push the .yml file into multiple repositories over multiple organisations

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $baselocation "https://github.com/xxxxxxx-xxxx/"
repocount='gitrepo.csv | wc -l'
for i in 'gitrepo.csv'
do 
 reponame="$i"
 cd $baselocation/$i
 cp source.yaml .
 git add .
 git commit -m "Create source.yaml"
 done
```

Answer (score 1):

Heh, I just did something similar. Here's the meat of the problem, where I have all the repos checked out in the current directory.

I don't particularly recommend this, but it's something I threw together in five minutes for a task I had this weekend.

```
#!/bin/bash

target=some_file.yml
message="Update YAML file"

ls */.git | perl -lpe 's|/.*||' | while read -r line
do
    pwd
    git checkout master
    git pull
    ... update the target here ...
    git diff --exit-code $target
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
      echo "NO CHANGES"
      continue
    fi
    git add $target
    git commit -m "$message" $target
    git push origin $branch 2>&1
done
```

Comment: i have elaborated the issue above kindly help

Comment: Well, in your example you left out the push.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat youfile.csv`
do
 base_location="Directory path"
 reponame=${i}
 echo ${reponame}
 cp Directory path/source.yaml Directory path/tmp/source.yaml
 cd ${base_location}
 mkdir ${reponame}
 cd ${reponame}
 sed -e "s/Variable-1,2/$reponame/g" '/Directory path/tmp/source.yaml'
 git init
 git clone https://Token@github.com/yourusername${i}.git
 cd ${reponame}
 cp Directory path/tmp/source.yaml .
 git add source.yaml
 git commit -m "Create source.yaml"
 git push --set-upstream $reponame master
 rm Directory path/tmp/source.yaml
 cd Directory path
done
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).